# ImageView - getImageBitmap()?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an **ImageView** with `visibility = View.VISIBLE` and predefined `width` and `height` in XML.

When I set in my code `ImageBitmap` like

```
someImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

how can I later on know is there some image bitmap already defined or it's still empty (null)?

So something like `someImageView.getImageBitmap() == null` ...I cannot test width, height or visibility because it's already predefined and it's the same thing if there is a bitmap or not.

Comment: Have you tried `getDrawable()`? I imagine that `setImageBitmap()` turns around and wraps the `Bitmap` in a `BitmapDrawable`. That's just a guess, though.

Comment: Just saw this. Its nice you figure it out! Thanks CommonsWare. My answer is pretty similar to this. With that way, you can get the bitmap from the imageview, and reuse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your imageView doesn't contain a bitmap if:

```
imageView.getDrawable() == null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try{
    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) someImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

 //re-use bitmap somehow?
    }
catch(NullPointerException e){
//Bitmap dont exists

}
```

Comment: This will crash with a `NullPointerException` if `getDrawable()` returns `null`.

Comment: you are right. just surrounded it. anyway, you solution in this case is better!